# Is F5 Big-IP Routing by DNS Names (on one IP address and port) Possible?

Tags: f5-big-ip, url-routing

In IIS, it is possible to listen for many DNS names on one IP address and port and then direct users to different websites based on the DNS name.

Is the same thing possible with F5 Big-IP devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This can be done with either HTTP Class profiles or an iRule on the virtual server you are configuring.

A sample iRule to get you started would look something like this:

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
   if { [HTTP::host] eq "www.mydomain.com" } {
         pool mydomain_Pool
      } else {
         pool other_Pool
      }
   }
}
```

I suggest using F5's DevCentral site at http://devcentral.f5.com/

Comment: +1 for DevCentral. It rocks.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it must be possible. Someone on the network team who manages the F5 servers in my company told me it wasn't!

Comment: HTTP Class profiles are deprecated in 11.4 and you will need to use a Local Traffic Policy going forward.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, though it requires writing iRules for them and associating the iRule to the virtual server. I don't believe there is a GUI way to do this.

Comment: If you're interested in doing it via a GUI form, check out the HTTP Class profiles.